# setting same dom element for inserting different data

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, click

In JAVASCRIPT  I have three different buttons, when i click first button I want to show some html data in the browser inside a html element and when I click second button I want to show different html data inside same html element and also I want previous data to remove. same with the third button. how can I do that with JAVASCRIPT?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="container"></main>

    <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button id="button3">Button 3</button>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
        const button2 = document.getElementById('button2')
        const button3 = document.getElementById('button3')

        const html1 = '<table><tr><td>Table 1</td></tr></table>'
        const html2 = '<table><tr><td>Table 2</td></tr></table>'
        const html3 = '<table><tr><td>Table 3</td></tr></table>'

        button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const container =  document.getElementById('container')
            container.innerHTML = html1
        });

        button2.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const container =  document.getElementById('container')
            container.innerHTML = html2
        });

        button3.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const container =  document.getElementById('container')
            container.innerHTML = html3
        });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THanks but i just have 1 query how previous html data will remove when we click next button?

Comment: The previous html data is currently removing when we click next button because you are replacing all the innerHTML.
If you want for instance only remove it you could do container.innerHTML = ''

Comment: thanks man you are great i was having confusion with this one issue ,you just solved that.thanks